# object variable is unaccesible in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var cashRegister = {
    total:0,

    add: function(itemCost){
        total += this.itemCost;
    },

    scan: function(item) {
        switch (item) { 
        case "eggs": 
            this.add(0.98); 
            break;

        case "magazine":
            this.add(4.99);
            break;

        }
        return true;
    }
};

cashRegister.scan("eggs");    
cashRegister.scan("magazines");

console.log('Your bill is '+cashRegister.total);
```

the output show NAN, and total is undefined. I tried `cashRegister.total` and `this.total` in the add method, no luck. What's wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `this` at wrong place. The line inside `add` should have been like this

```
this.total += itemCost;
```

When you say

```
total += this.itemCost;
```

1. `total` is not defined yet within the function
2. `this.itemCost` means that you are using the element `itemCost` which is in the current object. But that is actually not there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
var cashRegister = {
    total:0,

    add: function(itemCost){
        this.total += itemCost;
    },

    scan: function(item) {
        switch (item) { 
        case "eggs": 
            this.add(0.98); 
            break;

        case "magazine":
            this.add(4.99);
            break;

        }
        return true;
    }
};

cashRegister.scan("eggs");    
cashRegister.scan("magazines");

console.log('Your bill is '+cashRegister.total);
```

Your mistake was at this line:

```
total += this.itemCost;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the `add` method to:

```
add: function(itemCost){
    this.total += itemCost; // "this" was in the wrong place
}
```

Also, you shouldn't ever use floating-point numbers for money - they're not accurate! Use integers as cents instead. Don't convert to dollars until you need to display the dollar amount. Otherwise you might have magical fractions of cents which can add up over time.

```
var magicDollars = 1.10 + 2.20;
console.log( magicDollars );  // 3.3000000000000003 - Not good! Money can't materialize itself.

var cents = 110 + 220;
var realDollars = cents / 100;
console.log( realDollars );  // 3.3 - Better. No unexpected fractional cents.
```